# Question Regarding Widening Wavelength

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

Here is my question:

For a function...

y = 1/pi * sin(pi * x^2)

...which can be rewritten as ...

$y = \frac{1}{\pi} \cdot \sin(\pi \cdot x^2)$

...the wavelengths get narrower and narrower the more left and right one goes.

How can the function be modified such that the wavelengths get wider?

Comment: `the wavelengths get narrower and narrower` Because $x^2$ increases with $|x|\,$. `How can the function be modified such that the wavelengths get wider` Replace $x^2$ with something that ***de***creases with $|x|\,$.

Comment: i.e. $\sin(e^{-x})$

Answer (score 0):

The wavelengths of $\sin(f(x))$ will decrease as $f(x)$ increases. Which is why $x^2$ causes the wavelength to decrease. See for example $\sin(e^x)$. So to find the opposite $f(x)$ should be some decreasing function. For instance, $\sin(x^{-2})$, shown below.

[image: plot image]

Comment: Sadly, this does not work. X near 0 is fine but both left and right ends are decreasing wavelengths.

Comment: @SeanDorman see my edit. $\sin(x^{-2})$ has your desired behavior near to the origin. So just stretch it out a bit (i.e. $\sin(1000 x^{-2})$)